# Dynamically created expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, expression

I try to creat an expression for Linq query dynamically but it gives just this message back:

> {Method = Internal Error evaluating expression}
>   I use Vs 2019 and .NET Core 3.1.
>               class Client {
>                  public string Name { get; set; }
>                  ...
>               }

```
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Client), "x");
        var member = Expression.Property(parameter, "Name");
        var constant = Expression.Constant("X Y");
        var exp = Expression.Equal(member, constant);
        var func = Expression.Lambda(exp, parameter).Compile();
```

Where do I make a mistake, please?

UPDATE

```
namespace Domain
{
public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Department { get; set; }

    public string CompanyPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string PrivateMobileNumber { get; set; }

    public string ComputerName { get; set; }

    public Guid InternetProviderId { get; set; }

    public virtual InternetProvider InternetProvider { get; set; }

    public string OtherInternetProvider { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Error must be somewhere else, I've tried this code and it's working just fine. Is there something that could cause the issue inside the Client class? Can you give us the entire definition of that class? Are you getting that error on the same line where you're calling Compile method?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Compile method causes the problem, the expression 'exp' seem to be correct.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on, here is the working example of your code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nmXbfa

Basically no changes and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expression.Lambda` method has a generic version that allows to specify the delegate type, the last line can be modified to:

```
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Client, bool>>(exp, parameter).Compile();
```

Example of use:

```
var list = new List<Client>
{
    new Client() { Name = "X Y"}
};

var l2 = list.Where(func).ToList();
```

Working example: [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/94XcWZ).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the result is the same.

Comment: added a working example to the answer, please try it out.

Comment: But I want to use it in a Blazor apllication.

Comment: Thanks, it works but I do not know why. Maybe you are a computer shaman. :)